# Automatic double single quote ' in dreamweaver cs5.5

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to disable automatic write of the second single quote `'` when you press the first `'` ?

Dreamweaver when you type `'` it adds automatically the second `'`.

Any way to disable this?

Comment: Agree with you man, this is a really annoying "feature"... +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, Preferences, Code Hints.  Uncheck Jquery code hints.

Comment: THANK YOU this is has been driving me nuts for the longest time

Answer (score -1):

Never heard that character called 'apex' before, typically heard it called single quote or apostrophe, however, no, you cannot turn this feature off.

Comment: auto translate :P i was in doubt too that's why i typed it so many times :D